# Why can Python not see previously imported modules?

Tags: python, python-internals

Suppose there are two files `a.py` and `b.py`. Inside them are the following:

```
# a.py
from b import foo

foo()

# b.py
import os

def foo():
    print(os.cwd())
```

This works just fine, but why is `a.py` unable to see the imports of `b.py` implicitly for its  own use:

```
# a.py
import b

def bar():
    print(os.cpu_count())  # fails

b.foo()
bar()

# b.py
import os

def foo():
    print(os.cwd())
```

I am reading the [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) docs but haven't been able to figure this out. The `os` import exists in the namespace of `b.py` but it's not available to `a.py` and I am unsure why. The `globals()` method is at the module level, so given the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/8087992), is there no sharing of imports between modules (without using `__all__` and `*` imports)? Does each module get its own import namespace?

Comment: `os` is only imported inside of `b`. That means that `os` is local to that file. However, because you've imported `b`, you can access `os` using `b.os`. Unless you issue a star-import like: `from b import *` then they will have their own namespaces.

Comment: Each module has its own namespace _period_. `import` does two things: It pulls a module into the import cache if it isn't already there, _and_ adds references (pointing into that cache) to the current module's `__globals__` (aka that current module's namespace).

Comment: @HampusLarsson, ...sure, `from os import *` means that you aren't adding a reference into `os` from the current module's namespace (but instead adding separate references to each element in `os.__all__`), but that doesn't mean it's any less true that the module still has its own namespace, which is how I interpret your last sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each module has its namespace.
The import statement does two things: if a module is not yet imported in the current process, it is loaded and executed. After that its name is bound to the local namespace where the import statement is.

If a module already had been imported in the same process, *it is not reloaded*, but the names in the import statement are correctly bound by the import statement.

The correct thing to do is to add another `import os` on your `a` module -
but if you do `import b` you can use `b.os.cwd()` (as "os" is a bound name in the module `b` after it is executed)

Comment: And in fact, `os` is one of the modules typically created by the interpreter on startup, so `import os` virtually *always* only creates a new name in the local namespace bound to the module accessbile via `sys.modules['os']`.